# Node js TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to access Dashboard but I'm getting an error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

I have created a route to access DASHBOARD using Express Router. ('routes/index')

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const User = require('../models/User')

router.get("/dashboard", async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const users = await User.find({ user: req.user.id }).lean() //This line is generating the error
        res.render("dashboard", {
            name: req.user.name,
            users
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.render('error/500')
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

I have added this route in my app.js file

```
app.use('/',require('./routes/index'))
```

This is my MongoDB Database Schema ('models/User')

```
const mongoose =require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    confirmpassword: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    tokens: [{
        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }],
    role: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I have successfully registered and saved a user in my database

```
[Database Entry][1]
```

Comment: can you paste `request body` please, like what body you are giving.

Comment: Did you tried debugging req.user.id ?

Comment: can you show us what you're getting when you log `req.user.id` ?

Comment: I'm getting `undefined` when I type `console.log(req.body)` or `console.log(req.user)`

Comment: Whenever I use `req.user`, `req.body`, etc. I'm getting `undefined`. I can't access the database attributes. Now even `req.user.tokens` is not working which was working fine prior to this error.

Answer (score 0):

So error is because, your `id` is not define.
Please `console.log(req.user)` or `console.log(req.body)`, you will know what you are getting.

Comment: I'm getting undefined. My code was working yesterday I don't know how I'm getting error now. How do I fix this?

Comment: you might be using postman i guess, this mean you arent sending the request body. So thats why you are getting undefined error, can you paste your postman body?
Also have you tried `console.log(req.body)`? is it also coming as undefined?

Comment: No, I'm using MongoDB Database. I tried `console.log(req.body)`, it is showing undefined

Comment: Are you storing any information in user tokens? since its a get request and only way you will get a id if you store it in token? Can you try to login again?

Answer (score 0):

Request doesn't include `user` object. You should get empty array when `console.log(req.body)`.

You can do like this:

```
req.user = await User.findById(yourdata.id)
```

Then you can use `req.user.id`